# Hibernate : Flexible configuration of ID Generators (Identity, Sequential or Table)

Tags: hibernate

In our current product (that uses Spring boot-4.2.4 and hibernate-5.1) we intend to make the choice of Id Generators more flexible.
That is at the entity level we dont want to map any specific generators (like Identity, Table or Sequence). All that we will mention is whether this entity will be part of bulk inserts or not.
Then at the runtime based on db dialect and user configured value we will map one of the appropriate generators.
I had tried the below options:
**Option 1:** (Specifying a custom delegator generator in @GenericGenerator)
During custom generator instantiation, based on the runtime confgurations we can set the delegator(either Identity, Table or Sequence) and then delegate all calls to it.

```
    //Entity Class
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="generic")
    @GenericGenerator(name="generic", strategy = "src.test.CustomGenerator")
    public Long getId() {
    return id;
    }


// Custom Generator
public class CustomGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

    IdentifierGenerator delegator;

    public CustomGenerator() {
        if (true) //Condition based on config, dialect etc
            delegator = new IdentityGenerator();
        else
            delegator = new SequenceStyleGenerator();

    }

    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return delegator.generate(session, object);
    }
}
```

The problem with this option is, only some of the generators will implement interfaces like PostInsertIdentifierGenerator, PersistentIdentifierGenerator etc.
Custom generator cannot implement all these interfaces since the underlying delegator may not support those operations. On the other hand, if the custom generator did not implement any of these, we may loose on the hibernate optimizations.
**Option 2:** (Using IdGeneratorStrategyInterpreter)
I could have a custom implementation of IdGeneratorStrategyInterpreter that would return the appropriate generator type based on the conditions checked. But not sure how to make hibernate aware of this configuration through Spring.
**Option 3:** (Override the generator for each entity)
In case if we could get a hook from hibernate when the meta data for each entity is being build, we could override the generator. Provided this should not cost too much time.
Would appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: Have anyone found a solution to set IdGeneratorStrategyInterpreter (Option 2)?
These impls are not loaded via SPI like a lot of others in hibernate.